# Variable scope problem with super object

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble creating a "super object" (similar to that of CodeIgniter) for a framework project I'm working on.

I want to make a super object that all of my other classes will run through. I did that, but it seems I am unable to use my super object's object in each of my classes without using the global keyword in every function.

I have something like this:

```
class a
{
    function aa()
    {
        return 'class a';
    }
}

class b
{
    function bb()
    {
        $blah->a->aa();
    }
}

class superobj
{
    function loadClass($class)
    {
        $this->$class = new $class;
    }
}

class blah extends superobj
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->loadClass('a');
        $this->loadClass('b');
    }
}

$blah = new $blah;
```

So if I run this, I get an error because I can't access the aa method. If I put global $blah into the method bb, then it works (or at least in my real project it does, I dunno about this 5 second mockup hehe).

So is there any way to either make the $blah object global so that I don't need to reference it for every method, OR is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

I'm not very good at OOP...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234445/php-global-variables

Answer (score 3):

```
function bb() {
    $blah->a->aa();
}
```

Indeed, as with any function, this function has no variables in its scope. `$blah` was neither passed to the function nor is it defined in the function, so it doesn't exist.

If your objects depend on an instance of `blah` to work, you should pass it to the constructor.

```
class b {

    var $blah = null;

    function __construct($blah) {
        $this->blah = $blah;
    }

    function bb() {
        $this->blah->foo();
    }
}

$b = new b($instanceOfBlah);
```

Alternatively, use a static class that holds references to global objects and returns them on request (Registry pattern, like `$blah = Registry::get('blah')`).

Don't use `global`. Just don't.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this to blah's constructor, so that every class that extends blah would automatically be able to use its methods?

Comment: @Scott If a class *extends* blah, of course it'll be able to use blah's methods just like its own.

Comment: I will try to explain this, bare with me. If I load "class b" through "superobj", just like I am doing in my example above, I cannot use "class a"'s methods. If I load "class b" outside of superobj, then it DOES work. However I need it to be able to load through superobj, so I only ever have to use one object for all of my libraries. EDIT: Note that in my above example I am not extending blah, however in my real project I am, and calling $this->a->aa, for example, does not work.

Comment: @Scott Sorry, I'm not sure what you're aiming at here. You may be misunderstanding something about how OO works. You're also talking about two separate things: *extending objects* and *accessing methods of other objects* and how these objects should be passed around. Maybe you could provide a more concrete example about what you want to achieve, with more useful names than "a" and "blah"?

Comment: Well basically, I am trying to get around the lack of multiple inheritance in PHP. I would like to create a "master" class that all other classes run through, so that I have one simple object that can access all methods. I essentially want what the CodeIgniter framework does. I suppose maybe I will have to spend the time to dig through the CodeIgniter core and see what is going on.

Comment: @Scott Okay... The best way around multiple inheritance (actually, the best way, period, even if multiple inheritance existed) is composition. You're doing that with the `blah` class; a `blah` object is composed of a bunch of other objects, so `blah` has access to (methods of) `a` and `b`. `a` and `b` are *not* composed objects though, they're stand alone objects, neither inheriting nor otherwise acquiring any additional methods. `a` and `b` will either have to do the same thing `blah` does (extension and composition) or use one of the methods I described above.