# Why are static methods untestable?

Tags: php, unit-testing, static-methods

Why are static methods untestable? Kindly exemplify (in PHP if possible).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Static methods themselves aren't untestable, but if the object being tested calls a static method then a test cannot "get in between" and make it call a stub method instead. If the object being tested instead calls a regular method, the test can give it an alternative object with a stub implementation of that method.

In general, rigid dependencies are less testable while *dependency injection* (google it) makes code more testable.

For instance, let's say we have a static method `getCurrentUser()` that is used by the class we are testing, as follows

```
class PostModel {
    //...
    public function getRecentPosts() {
        return $this->database->from('posts')
                ->where(array('user' => UserModel::getCurrentUser()))
                ->limit(10);
    }
}
```

Now `UserModel::getCurrentUser()` cannot be replaced with a stub method. If we make it a regular method that we call through an object reference instead, we can pass in an alternative stub object in our test.

```
class PostModel {
    private $userModel;
    public function __construct($userModel) { 
        $this->userModel = $userModel;
    }
    //...
    public function getRecentPosts() {
        return $this->database->from('posts')
                ->where(array('user' => $this->userModel->getCurrentUser()))
                ->limit(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to illustrate this (an example)?

Comment: Why not?
I can't get your point. if you have problem about dependency injection, I think you should pass user object to getRecentPosts instead entire class and I think you can not test easily PostModel because your pattern is wrong.
No problem about testing static methods.
If I have mistake please clear it for me.

Comment: Yes, getting the dependency as a function parameter would work too.

Answer (score 4):

Static methods are testable: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html (it's in php), but if you want to test the interactactions between classes (i.e. using mocks and fake objects) you will probably prefer not to use it. That being said phpunit 3.5 allows you to stub these.

You might also want to look at [When do I use static variables/functions in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257371/when-do-i-use-static-variables-functions-in-php) or search for some information about when to use static methods.

I use static methods inside a class (ie marked private or protected) as they are faster in the language I work with.

Comment: Yes, PHPUnit apparently now supports unit testing of static methods. But Sebastian Berghman mentions it as only a workaround for untestable code.

Answer (score 3):

Well-defined  `Static` methods are perfectly testable. You see, the problem isn't with the method itself, it's with the method's dependencies. If the method and its dependencies (and the dependencies' dependencies) are [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), then there's no problem. Problems arise when your `Static` methods are calling other methods that are, for example, dependant on a `global`.