# In PHP when do I use :: and when do I use ->

Tags: php, function, object

I apologise if this seems obvious to the more experienced PHP users, however, I do believe I have missed an important block in my learning journey. When using objects, how do I now to call the function through -> or call it using :: . At the moment I have only been using the -> method however I have come across code using the :: method. Any insight or explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Its static scope. You can get more info at those links.

[php manual oop5 static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)
[php manual variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
[php manual late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Oh also class constans calling with the dots too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to read those links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

-> is for **objects** method and properties so when you create object of class you need to use ->

```
$someObject = new someClass();
$someObject->someMethod();
```

:: is for **static** method and properties of **class**, which means you do not need to create object to use it:

```
someClass::someMethod()
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. So basically when you reference the object that is "static" you use the "::" However when you have the object instantiated in a variable you reference it using the ->.

Comment: @OliverChalk no, you refer to the class' members with `::`

Comment: No, there is no such thing like static object. There is class. You can call directly class instead of create object from class. someClass::someMethod() - this is call static method *someMethod* of class *someClass*. You do not create objects to call static methods of class

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I said "Object" but yes the Class is the item that is static and is referenced using "::"

Comment: @OliverChalk and wrong again. Class is not static. Method of class is static ;)

Comment: I think it's best if I stop assuming things >.>

Answer (score 5):

You use `::` when you are calling a **static** method or variable, or when calling parent class (if current class is extended).

You use `->` when you are calling a method or variable that the class has to be instantiated.

Have a look Classes and Objects [self and $this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/151969/1255289) and Variable scope [Static properties and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1257371/1255289).